# Use nearest neighbor algorithm to find lookalike population

Tags: sas, nearest-neighbor

Nearest neighbor can classify new data point based on the k nearest neighbor's class. Assuming there is dataset A contains 10000 data points. There is also another dataset B contains 1 MM data points. The goal is to find the most similar records from dataset B that resembles dataset A on a number of pre-decided attributes(features). 
SAS has a couple of procedure can do that such as PROC DISCRIM that takes a training data and classify on the test data such as below. In this case, how to define training data as the purpose is just to find the most similar records in dataset B that looks like each individual records in data A?

```
proc discrim data=train
method=npar k=5
testdata=toscore
testout=toscore_out
;
class y;
var x1-x10;
run;
```

Comment: This is an unsupervised learning problem - you don't have training data or know what the results should be. If you have a list of specific features that you're interested in, calculate a distance between the one record and all the other records and pick the records with the smallest distance. This is going to be computationally intensive. Also, this isn't a programming problem - it's a methodology question and not suitable for SO. Try posting this on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you have access to Enterprise Miner or Factory Miner? There are a number of procedures built into it for this very problem.

Comment: Stu, do you know which module or SAS procedure in Enterprise Miner can do that?